# How can I import data into read-only datasheet fields?

Tags: sharepoint, view, datasheet

I am importing data from Excel into SharePoint list using the "Datasheet view".

When I paste the data, I get error message "Cell is read only." for read-only fields.

Is there a way to import data into read-only fields.?

Comment: Why are they read-only? Are these calculated fields?

Comment: You can't overwrite the result of a calculated field - they are... erm... calculated.

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan mentioned, it isn't possible to overwrite the results of a calculated field.

My recommendation would be to remove the calculated columns from the view the datasheet is based on, then add the columns the calculations are based on (if they're not already displayed).

You can then paste the source data for those calculations in, automatically populating the results.